# Python NLTK using local nltk_data

Tags: python-3.x, nltk

I've been recently working with NLTK library for language processing. I can normally install packages using nltk.download('package'), if I have the internet access etc.

The problem arises, If I try to run my code offline on a cluster. Here,

```
from nltk.tag import PerceptronTagger
ImportError: cannot import name 'PerceptronTagger'
```

and similar errors emerge, as nltk can't seem to find the nltk_data folder. I tried:

1. nltk.data.path.append("./nltk_data"), where I copied nltk_data along with code.
2. nltk.download('punct') #,download_dir="./nltk_data"), but this doesn't work, as there is no internet access.

Question is then, how can I use nltk_data locally?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It appears the machine I was running this on had NLTK 3.0.2, hence updating NLTK solved the problem all together.